# How to use selection formula for crystal report for datetime column un vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

My problem is,How to set value to selection formula in crystal report for datetime column(im using sql server 2000).
eg:

```
selectionFromula="{tblMain.bday}='"& datetimepicker.value &"'"
```

when i use this, a error message is showing problem with selection formula.but when i use for another column,it work well like this,

```
selectionFormula="{tblMain.id}='"& txtid.text &"'"
```

but when it use for datetime type column,it doesn't work.can some one give me a working example for this.thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending a string literal to the selection formula instead of a date.  So, for example, if the datetimepicker.value is "1/1/2000", then Crystal would see

```
{tblMain.bday}='1/1/2000'
```

Either the string needs to be converted to a date value, or it needs to be flagged as a date literal using the pound sign (#).

One of these should be what Crystal sees.

```
//Using a conversion to a Crystal Date
{tblMain.bday}=CDate('1/1/2000')

//Using the Crystal Date literal
{tblMain.bday}=#1/1/2000#
```

So your selection formula in VB would look like one of these

```
'Using a conversion to a Crystal Date
selectionFormula="{tblMain.bday}=CDate('"& datetimepicker.value &"')"

'Using the Crystal Date literal
selectionFormula="{tblMain.bday}=#"& datetimepicker.value &"#"
```